# Cannot set property 'nodeValue' of null

Tags: javascript, html, nodevalue

I'm going through a book and it seems to be right, but the following code keeps giving me the error: Cannot set property 'nodeValue' of null. The code makes sense to me, but I don't understand why it can't clear the text value when clicking the clear button.

```
var clear = function(){

        $("miles").firstChild.nodeValue = "";
        $("gallons").firstChild.nodeValue = "";
        $("mpg").firstChild.nodeValue = "";
         }

    window.onload = function () {
        $("calculate").onclick = calculateMpg;
        $("miles").focus();
        $("clear").onclick = clear;
    }
```

Html

```
<section>
    <h1>Calculate Miles Per Gallon</h1>
    <label for="miles">Miles Driven:</label>
    <input type="text" id="miles"><br>
    <label for="gallons">Gallons of Gas Used:</label>
    <input type="text" id="gallons"><br>
    <label for="mpg">Miles Per Gallon</label>
    <input type="text" id="mpg" disabled><br>
    <label>&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate MPG"><br>
    <input type="button" id="clear" value="clear"><br>
</section>
```

Comment: change to $("miles").get(0).firstChild.nodeValue = "" and similarly for others. That should fix your problem.

Comment: @elclanrs - I'm not sure they are using jQuery because `$("miles")` won't work either if it's jQuery.  I wonder if `$` is a synonym for `document.getElementById()`.  Also not, there's no jQuery tag on the question.

Comment: To the OP.  What is `$` in your project.  Is it jQuery?  Or is it `document.getElementById()`?  Also, please show us the relevant HTML so we can see whether your javascript is appropriately targeting the right objects.

Comment: Oh I see there's no jQuery tag... Yeah we need more info to figure out what `$` is...

Comment: I think it is prototype.js

Comment: Yeah, it's not jQuery. here is the full code: http://pastebin.com/ufGgAq74

Comment: So it's just a shortcut to `document.getElementById`.

Comment: yes , just a shortcut. shouldn't `firstchild.nodeValue = "";` clear the text field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input elements do not have child nodes so `firstChild` gives you null, further more if you're trying to clear the value of the input fields use the `value` property.

```
var clear = function(){
    $("miles").value = "";
    $("gallons").value = "";
    $("mpg").value = "";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is this where you use the `.value` property on the input fields directly:

```
var clear = function() {
    $("miles").value = "";
    $("gallons").value = "";
    $("mpg").value = "";
 }
```

---

Here's  an explanation of what was going on.  Now that we can see your full page and see that `$` is `document.getElementById()`, the issue is that you are some of those nodes don't have a firstChild.

For example the object with an `id="miles"` is an input tag and it has no children so `.firstChild` is `null`.

In this line:

```
$("miles").firstChild.nodeValue = "";
```

`$("miles")` gets you the DOM object.

`$("miles").firstChild` returns null because there are no children of that DOM object.

`$("miles").firstChild.nodeValue = "";` is an error because `$("miles").firstChild` is `null` and `null` doesn't have a property `.nodeValue`.

Comment: ok, I figured out the rest. I just had to use `$("miles").value = "";`. Thanks for the clear up!

Comment: @oxxi - why did you select a different answer as the best answer when I put a lot of work in with you in the comments to get you to show us what we needed in order to help you and I also provided the correct answer and I provided the first answer and I provided detailed explanation of what was wrong with your original code?

Comment: @jfriend00 You think help, hard work, and a great explanation deserves to be accepted? :)

Comment: @Ian - one can only hope, but alas I'm old enough to know the world isn't always fair, but at least I can ask.  Or perhaps the OP saw something uniquely insightful in the answer they did accept? :)

Comment: @jfriend00 It happens to me all the time, and I'm sure you've seen it plenty. Just keep working hard and it pays off sometimes :) I don't see anything *better* in the other answer, yet it is still valid :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code you posted in the comments, the problem is that `$("miles")` and the other elements don't have any children.

It seems like you're trying to do something like this:

```
var clear = function() {
    $("miles").value = "";
    $("gallons").value = "";
    $("mpg").value = "";
}
```

Comment: Now that you can see the HTML, it's fairly clear that the objects being targeted here are input fields and they never have children.